# Check if a variable equal X or Y

Tags: ruby, boolean

I'm stuck with something very basic in **Ruby**. Maybe I did not understand how the operator `||` works?

```
a_to_i = [a = 12, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0, g = 0, h = 0, i = 0]

puts a

puts a == (3 || 12)
```

I'm waiting the output :  `true`

But it returns `false` instead.

Do you see where am i doing wrong ? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is the first line supposed to do? Those assignments within the array don't look right.

Comment: @Stefan not all that different from `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = a_to_i = [12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

Answer (score 2):

`3 || 12` returns 3, as it is a truthy value.

You need to ask two questions here:

```
puts (a == 3 || a == 12)
```

Alternatively, if the list of options is slightly longer:

```
puts [3, 12].include? a
```

Comment: We can also use [12, 3].any?(a) to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the statment `(3 || 12)` is `3`, always resulting in `a == 3`. You'll need to check both values separately.

```
puts((a == 3) || (a == 12))
```